# How to Refresh Dependencies after Adding FreeType Extension in Android Project

Tags: android, libgdx, fonts, android-studio, gradle

I'm planning to use FreeType fonts in my game (LibGDX and Android Studio) and I already added the freetype dependencies in my project. How can I refresh the dependencies after adding them? I have found few similar questions regarding this topic but didn't offer much help. Here is an image of the dependencies:

[image]

Comment: what's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command for explicit refreshing

```
./gradlew --refresh-dependencies
```

but I guess your ide should resolve it after you save the gradle file.
You also can press `Sync Now` (not exactly sure what it does); it's on top right on your screenshot.

The command was taken from here: 
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle#libgdx-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

There's a banner that says :

> Gradle files has changed since last project sync. A project sync may be necessary for the IDE to work properly

You can click`sync now` and it will refresh the `Gradle` project